# How do we detect particles from cosmic rays whose lifetimes are on the order of nanoseconds?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors, pions

I have read that the charged pions were experimentally discovered in 1947 using photographic emulsions placed on mountaintops so that as they came from cosmic rays, they wouldn't interact with the atmosphere as much. Their lifetimes are around 26 nanoseconds, so if they were travelling close to the speed of light at 300,000,000 m/s, then they could travel around 8 meters before decaying. So how are we able to detect them from cosmic rays from many millions of light-years away?

Comment: have a read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation to understand how time dilation affects tracks of cosmc  decaying particles

Answer (score 3):

The pions were not traveling in from outer space, they were formed when cosmic rays coming in from outer space struck atoms in the atmosphere and created the pions and muons too. Those particles then struck the film plate stacks which were surrounded with magnets so the damage path left behind after a charged particle blasted its way through the films would be bent in such a away that the charge of the particle could be determined.

The practice of using cosmic rays for particle physics research ended when powerful particle accelerators became available in the early to mid-1950's.

Comment: I would like to add here that usually stable particles like proton/alpha particles travels from sun to earth in cosmic rays. Unstable particles are generated in the atmosphere by interaction of protons/alpha particles with gases. There are some particles like muons moving with speed 0.9999c (gamma ~100) experience significant time dilation and they can be detected at ground even if they are generated at the top of atmosphere.